# NHibernate does not create Tables

Tags: nhibernate, schemaexport

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.Configure();
cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(<ClassName>).Assembly);
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, false);
```

The above piece of code is supposed to create a database Table with name `<ClassName>`.

But it is not creating.

Comment: For starters, have you looked into your config? Are the class mapping that you expect included?

Answer (score 7):

Your most likely problems:

- using SQLite with connection.release_mode=on_close
- no mapping files in the specified assembly
- mapping files have not been added to the assembly as an Embedded Resource
- mapping files are not named *.hbm.xml
- some table or column names should be quoted for SQL (this would be throwing an exception)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to Execute() must be true.

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(**true**, true, false, false);
```

I don't know why, but there you have it.